# How do I play Quake 3 online with my bro in another city?

Tags: quake-3

I bought Quake 3 from Steam and my bro did the same. We want to play together but it just does not seem that easy.

I tried to create a game through the game menu "create" gave the game a name and choose it to be internet. No matter what I do from here my bro cant find it.

We do live in different cities so it is not LAN.

How can we play Quake 3 together?

Thanks

Comment: Are your firewalls letting traffic through? Did you check what ports Quake is played through?

Comment: So the Ip shown up in the small window is a local IP with the port 27960 i think it is. Are you saying I should use my own IP from showmyip website?   Also i have not done anything on my internet router.

Comment: years ago my friends and I solved this problem by using vpn, basically we found a vpn provider online with a free tier for small number of people, created a vpn, connected to it, then used local ip addresses within that network to play the game. if I remember correctly, we used LogMeIn Hamachi, not sure if it's still around and if it's still free for small groups.

Comment: Software recommendation might not be ideal for the site but I typically resolve this issue with zerotierone or hamachi. Connect to your homie and launch a lan game.

Comment: hamachi you say. That do sound like a good solution. Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: we tried hamachi  but it just wont work for us... some vpn error and tunning error. Tried all the recommended actions..

Comment: Try *Quake Live* instead. I believe it's pretty much an updated version of *Quake III Arena*.